# How I can see a Image in my ImageButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, calendar, imagebutton

I write a ASP.NET Application for creating a signatur and other stuff. And I use the AjaxToolkit with the CalenderExtender. I want if I click on a ImageButton that open the extender and the TextBox get the Data. It works fine but I don't see the ButtonImage :( >.<

Where I can get a Image for my ImageButton and how it works? Here my ASPX Site Code

```
 ...
<tr>
                                <td>Abwesenheit von: </td><td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAbwesenheitVon" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAbwesenheitVon" runat="server" ToolTip="Abwesenheit von..." PostBackUrl="~/App_Theme/Calender.ico" />
                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="AbwesenheitVon" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAbwesenheitVon" 
                                                      Format="dd.MM.yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgbtnAbwesenheitVon"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
    ...
```

My second Question is.
Can I use a Label for the textBox, too?

But I see only this..._->

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
PostBackUrl="~/App_Theme/Calender.ico"
```

with

```
ImageUrl = "~/App_Theme/Calender.ico"
```

[`Image.ImageUrl` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use **ImageUrl** property instead of **PostBackUrl**

Comment: You could use jQuery datepicker UI widget from http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/